# Problem with Mac HDMI - Thunderbolt display to Sony (not a cable problem)

Tags: macos, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I have a 13-inch Macbook Pro with Mountain Lion installed. I bought an HDMI - Thunderbolt cable months ago in order to watch movies, TV shows and whatnot on my TV (Sony Bravia). The cable had been working out great for me since I bought it; the audio and video quality was exceptional and it gave me an almost perfect HD experience whenever I watched shows on my TV via my Macbook.

However, the last couple days I have been running into some major problems with this display connection and has left me quite confused and frustrated. Basically, the Macbook is no longer able to detect the display! I connect the TV to the laptop and ensure that the connection settings are proper (ie, I have connected to HDMI 1 and proeprly set the TV's input to HDMI 1 as well). The Macbook's screen will flash once and the TV will go from the blue "No Signal" screen to a blank black screen. Previously, this is when the extended screen from the Macbook would appear on the TV and I can drag windows onto the screen. Unfortunately, none of these occur (can neither see the computer screen on my TVnor be able to drag windows onto the extended screen).

I have tried a plethora of troubleshooting steps; I have restarted the computer many times, turned the TV off and on, tried connecting the cable at different times (when just TV is off, when just Macbook is off, etc). I have also read up endless forum posts about this issue, but have yet to found a worthy solution (sorry, to many forum posts to put on this Question. It is a simple Google search away...)

Before I beg the world for help, I would like to share one piece of pertinent information that may be helpful. I have isolated this to a **Macbook problem**, not a problem with the **cable** or **TV.** I connected my other laptop (a Dell XPS with Windows 7 installed) to the computer with the same HDMI - Thunderbolt cable and I was able to successfully watch a Simspons episode on the TV with top-quality audio and video.

All help is much appreciated, especially if it saves me a trip to the local Apple Store. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -3):

I solved this one!
make sure your digital tv isn't on

Comment: This will need some more explanation. The setup of the question implies the TV is on since it's showing the blue "no input screen". If you want to go out on a limb and describe when the TV should be off, what happens and when to turn it on so things work, we might have an actual answer (even if it's wrong, it will let people think over the process).